# looping through substrings in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, string, loops, substring, swift-playground

What is the best way to loop through a substring in Swift 3.0?

```
var start = s.startIndex
var end = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)
   for i in start...end {


   }
```

The following code throws an error: `Type ClosedRange<String.Index> (aka ‘ClosedRange<String.CharacterView.Index>’) does not conform to Sequence protocol`.

Answer (score 2):

`start` and `end` are types of `String.Index`, and they cannot be used in a for loop; instead, you can get `substring` within the following range:

```
var start = s.startIndex
var end = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)
let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: start, upper: end))
let subString = s.substring(with: range)
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Index` cannot be used in a for loop, but (sub)strings can be  `enumerated`

```
var start = s.startIndex
var end = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)
for (index, character) in s[start...end].enumerated() {
    print(index, character)
}
```